# Dynamic equivalent of innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I want to get the innerHTML of an element that may have been changed by the user.

So, for example, I want to know the state of a radio button:

```
<input type="radio" name="Q_209" value="A" checked>
```

or

```
<input type="radio" name="Q_209" value="A">
```

In modern browsers, innerHTML just gives the original tag when the page was loaded (as [discussed at length here](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=317838#1744233)): it doesn't record whether the radio button has been checked by the user or not.

Is there any safe way to get the updated HTML? I know that there are ways to get the state of the radio button itself in Javascript, but what I would like is the full, updated HTML.

Thanks!

Comment: That's a good question. As far as I know, there is no way to do that with existing functionality, you probably have to build your own function for that which might be quite heavy - perhaps someone wiser will prove otherwise.

Comment: no answer, just FYI: IE8 actually does show the current CHECKED state.

Can you explain why you need this? there is probably another solution.

Comment: So based on the post you linked, it seems that the effect on the HTML when updating a form input is undefined. Therefore you can't count on just looking a the HTML. What we really need to do is transform the current DOM object of interest into HTML somehow. which I can't think of a simple way to do.

Comment: If you explain why you need to do this, we could probably find a good workaround that won't involve writing your own HTML-generating function.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. The reason is that I'm writing a quiz; it shows one question at a time, but I would like to record which answer the user gives for each, so that I can display all the questions and answers they gave together at the end. <br/>In other words, I'd like to save the innerHTML for each question somewhere with the answer state, to make it easy to redisplay. It would be nice to use the HTML directly rather than storing the answers somewhere in a Javascript array and then having to write another function to display the radio buttons again. But, if that's what it takes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the actual order of an HTML element's properties is open to interpretation by the browser, so there's no reliable way to determine if you're dealing with `<input type="radio" name="Q_209" value="A" checked>` or `<input checked="true" name="Q_209" value="A" type="radio">`

But, you can get all of the properties and values of an element with `for ... in` statement:

```
var foo = document.getElementById('form_id')['Q_209'];
var foo_properties = [];

for (var prop in foo) {
   // do something with prop and foo[prop];      
}
```

This means you could potentially compare the properties found in the element against a subset of properties you actually care about (specific to this particular tag or a larger universe of "html" properties) to get the "html state" of the element and be able to reconstruct it, or a string representation of it.

```
var input_foo = document.getElementById('form_id')['Q_209'];
var awesome_properties = {'type':'','name':'','value':'','checked':''};
var tag = '<input ';
var properties = '';

for (var prop in foo) {
   if (prop in awesome_properties) {
      properties += ' '+prop+'="'+foo[prop]+'"';
   }
}

tag += properties;
tag += '>';

window.alert(tag);
```

Comment: "I know that there are ways to get the state of the radio button itself in Javascript, but what I would like is the full, updated HTML."

Comment: Taking this as an accepted answer, as it seems to be the best way to do what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As has been mentioned, the HTML doesn't store the *current* state of form elements. HTML defines the initial or *default* state of form elements. The DOM stores the volatile form state.

For example, this HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="Q_209" value="A" checked>
```

would set the defaultChecked property of the element to true, which would persist even if a different radio button in the group were checked.

Changing the defaultChecked property does appear to update the outerHTML.

So, if you loop through all of the form elements copying the current value/checkedness/selectedness to the defaultValue/defaultChecked/defaultSelected properties, you may then be able to get the updated outerHTML you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you want the [:checked](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/checked) in jQuery and

```
$('input[type=radio]:checked').html()
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to walk the DOM tree and generate the HTML yourself

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that the HTML is not really "updated". The DOM tree is, and that's what you can see, but the HTML *per se* stays the same (and that's why innerHTML keeps the same value)

Comment: Useful to know, but not a solution to the OP's problem. I won't -1 because it's important to understand the difference, though.

Comment: The DOM tree isn't really changed either, just the state related to a particular node.